# Excel custom data validation use own made function

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I'm trying to use my own made function inside custom data validation formula.
But for some reason it does not work. 

My function:

```
Public Function IsNumberXValid(x) As Boolean
   IsNumberXValid = IsNumeric(x) And Math.Cos(x) <> 1
End Function
```

When I put this function inside formula field it shows following warning:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried to `Name` the formula ??

Comment: No, I haven't tried @Gary'sStudent

Comment: See below..........................

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With normal worksheet functions, it is easy to apply ***DV***:

[image]

It is slightly more complex with a *UDF()*  This approach uses a "helper" cell.

I begin with a tiny *UDF()*:

```
Public Function IsPrime(L As Long) As Boolean
    arr = Array(5, 7, 11)
    IsPrime = False
    For Each a In arr
        If L = a Then
            IsPrime = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next a
End Function
```

The *UDF()* returns `True` for a couple of inputs.  I want to apply ***DV*** to cell **D1** using the *udf()* as a rule.

I am using cell **E1** as my "helper".  In cell **E1** I put my *UDF()*:

```
=IsPrime(D1)
```

[image]

Next I `Name` my "helper" cell:

[image]

Finally, I return to cell **D1** and apply the ***DV***:

[image]

Comment: Interesting approach!

Comment: @EdgarsŠturms  I am using Excel 2007 on a Win 7 machine............does this work for you ??